# How do I cleanly "reattach" a detached method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Say I have this class:

```
class Foo
  def destroy_target(target)
    Missile.launch(target)
  end
end
```

I want to *temporarily* neuter the destructive power of `Foo`, for example for testing purposes, so I do this:

```
backup = Foo.instance_method(:destroy_target)

class Foo
  def destroy_target(target)
    Pillow.launch(target)
  end
end
```

Here's my question: how do I "reattach" the original method to `Foo`, as if it was never overridden in the first place?

I realize I can do this:

```
class Foo
  def destroy_target(target)
    backup.bind(self).call(target)
  end
end
```

But obviously this is not optimal, as I'm now wrapping the original function. I want to be able to detach and reattach the method an indefinite amount of times without adding any overhead.

Asked a different way; how do I attach a `DetachedMethod` to a class "properly", i.e. without defining a new method that calls the detached one.

---

Note: I am not interested in alternative ways of temporarily changing the functionality of a class. I specifically want to know how to replace a method with a different method, then restore the original method cleanly.

Comment: `backup = Foo.instance_method(:destroy_target)` without `s`

Comment: Do you want to replace the method for a specific `Foo` instance or class-wide, i.e. for all `Foo`s?

Answer (score 2):

I tested your first example, and it seems to work fine. I couldn't find any side-effect, but it doesn't mean there isn't.

Did you consider [refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html)?

## For a Class

```
class Missile
  def self.launch(t)
    puts "MISSILE -> #{t}"
  end
end

class Pillow
  def self.launch(t)
    puts "PILLOW -> #{t}"
  end
end

class Foo
  def destroy_target(target)
    Missile.launch(target)
  end
end

module PillowLauncher
  refine Foo do
    def destroy_target(target)
      Pillow.launch(target)
    end
  end
end

module Test
  using PillowLauncher
  Foo.new.destroy_target("Tatooine")
  #=> PILLOW -> Tatooine
end

Foo.new.destroy_target("Tatooine")
#=> MISSILE -> Tatooine
```

It might bring the advantage of being a bit more standard and understandable than your example.

## For a Module

If `Foo` is a `Module`, you cannot call `refine Foo` directly, you'd get a `TypeError: wrong argument type Module (expected Class)`.

You can, however, refine its `singleton_class` :

```
module Foo
  def self.destroy_target(target)
    Missile.launch(target)
  end
end

module PillowLauncher
  refine Foo.singleton_class do
    def destroy_target(target)
      Pillow.launch(target)
    end
  end
end

module Test
  using PillowLauncher
  Foo.destroy_target('Tatooine')
  #=> PILLOW -> Tatooine
end

Foo.destroy_target('Tatooine')
#=> MISSILE -> Tatooine
```

I'm not sure about your note :

> I am not interested in alternative ways of temporarily changing
>   the functionality of a class. I specifically want to know how to
>   replace a method with a different method, then restore the original
>   method cleanly.

My proposed code seems to do both.

Comment: Refinements look really cool, but apparently they only work with classes (not modules). In my current use case I need it to work with modules. Before Ruby version 2.3 they also had to be activated at top-level, i.e. they couldn't be activated inside a class or module as you demonstrate.

Comment: I tested this code with 2.1.5 and 2.2.1. I was actually surprised it worked, because the documentation only mentioned top-level refinements.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
Foo.instance_exec {
  define_method(:destroy_target, backup)
}
```

But I'm not completely sure if this is side effect free. If somebody knows for sure I'd appreciate a comment.

This also appears to work if `Foo` is a module defined like this:

```
module Foo
  extend self

  def destroy_target(target)
    Missile.launch(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: `define_method` seems correct, but I'd use `Foo.send(:define_method, :destroy_target, backup)` – it looks a little less invasive.